# Software to write HTML help files

Tags: html

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Can anyone recommend software to create HTML help files, preferably free.

Comment: If you are talking about CHM files, the Wikipedia article about CHM ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help ) says the following: *The Free Pascal project has a compiler (chmcmd) that can create CHM files in a multiplatform way.*

Answer (score 0):

Libreoffice Writer, part of the Libreoffice suite can save documents in HTML format.

---

Following [FedonKadifeli's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303203/linux-software-to-write-html-help-files#comment2215898_1303203) however, thinking along documentation generators, here is [a list of them on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators).

Without any personal experience using it, I would highlight [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) (Also, its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(documentation_generator))), because a high number of reputable projects use it (and I remember my positive impressions coming across some of them).

Here is [an example documentation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/battery.html), that demonstrate its features for providing ergonomic and eye-pleasing interfaces. To achieve that look in the example, it needs [this theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme).

The [Sphinx website's examples page](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/examples.html) also offers an insight into the range of projects / organizations that rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

For greater compatibility, I suggest writing the documentation in [Markdown format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) which is very simple and you can use free software (e.g. Visual Studio Code) to immediately see the formatted docs as you write. Afterwards, you can use one of several [available utilities](https://markdowntohtml.com/) to export Markdown to HTML or to several other formats (e.g. PDF, DOC, EPUB).